# PHP autoloader class vs. procedural autoloader function?

Tags: php, autoload, spl

Up to this point I've used procedural standalone autoloader functions and registered them with [spl_autoload_register()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload-register.php) to automatically load my (usually) namespaced classes. Lately, though, I've noticed people mentioning the use of autoloader classes in conjunction with some of the prominent PHP frameworks.

Almost all of my code is object oriented these days, but I don't really see advantages to using a class "Autoloader" over a basic function in this instance. And in terms of testability, I feel pretty good about using [class_exists()](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.class-exists.php) checks in my tests to verify that the procedural functions load files correctly.

**So my questions are three:**

1. What advantages or features (if any) might sway me to refactor things and start using a full blown object to autoload class files?
2. Am I missing some glaring advantages here outside the obvious OOP features?
3. Could you please make a case for either procedural or class autoloaders?

---

**UPDATE**

Below is some example code for a typical autoload function I might employ. It's metacode, so don't look for typos. I organize my directory structures so that they mirror the namespaces. The hypothetical `explode_namespaces()` function could theoretically be included as a static method alongside a static `autoload()` method in a class, so that's one benefit. It might be cleaner to combine these disparate "utility" functions as methods in a single class.

```
function autoload($class_name)
{
  $root = APP_LIBS; // a directory path constant set at config time

  if ($namespaces = explode_namespaces($class_name)) {

    $domain = array_shift($namespaces);
    $root  .= "/$domain/";

    $class_name = array_pop($namespaces);
    $directories = array();

    foreach ($namespaces as $directory) {
      $directories[] = $directory;
    }
    $root .= implode($directories, '/');
  }

  $file = "$root/$class_name.php";
  if (file_exists($file)) {
    include $file;
  }
}
```

Comment: I've removed the "answer" part from your question as it's irrelevant to the question really. You should consider adding your own answer, it will likely help others :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are comparing functions with methods. That's just syntactic sugar.

Unless you have a map-based autoloader or one that has a builtin dependency table you don't need any class-level attributes to keep track of things (or could resort to static or global vars otherwise). Runtime reconfigurability is not a real necessity in practice either.

You can make a procedural autoloader project-configurable with constants etc. Having constructor properties isn't that significant of a benefit for reuse with a method implementation. It only may look slightly nicer.

Answer (score 0):

Use the prebuilt one if you already use another major part of the framework, other wise it doesn't really matter.

Also, using one auto loader, with multiple namespaces/directories registered will cut down memory ever so slightly, but that's not really a concern.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I don't use said frameworks. I generally prefer to cherry pick my favorite features from various frameworks and I'm not looking to have a "You should use a framework" discussion :) Also, I'm currently using only one autoloader .. About to update question with sample code.